# Chrome extension: how to avoid refresh extension when develop content.js

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm on developing a chrome extension, most logic code is in the `content.js`, what upset me is, when the `content.js` code updated, I have to

1. Refresh extension by myself
2. Refresh the test web page

Is there something like `supervisor` in `node.js`,

when the `content.js` updated, it automatic refresh the extension even the web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know `supervisor` but I've seen that question a few times and came across some blog post, forum or GitHub issue just today actually.

The answer is "no there is no such thing".

To work around it, there are a few things. One of them is [Extensions Reloader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extensions-reloader/fimgfedafeadlieiabdeeaodndnlbhid) which adds a button to Chrome to reload your extensions. Check out their "reload by browsing" feature which could avoid having to click that button.

There are other similar solutions out there, but nothing as simple as what you describe.

Comment: The Extensions Reloader work for all file update except the `manifest.json` file.However, it enough for me now.Thank you

Comment: Yes, in most cases, that's sufficient once all your files are in place.